# Sending Zip files through mailx command

Tags: zip, mailx

I have a zip file named :  zip_final.zip

I have to attach this file as a attachment and send the mail.

Also, I have to display all the file_names present inside the zip file in the mail body.

I have this code :

```
export files_list=`unzip -Zl zip_final.zip`

mailx -a ${zip_final.zip} -s "Files list | Zip file" << EOM

   Hi team, sent zip file.
   Files inside it are  :  $files_list

   Thank you.

EOM
```

But the mail is not sent if I am doing this. Like the mail command is not even getting called/triggered. I am not even getting any error messages too.

**Can someone suggest how to send that zipfile as an attachment using mailx command and also display all the file names inside the zipfile in the mail body?**

Comment: The mail message protocol is ancient, and is ASCII-based. A zip file can contain any binary data, which is incompatible with the ASCII constraint. Mail attachments need to be encoded into base64 encoding for transmission, and declared using the appropriate Mime type so the receiving system knows how to decode them.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant `mailx` with `-a` parameter does exactly this - encodes the attachment and properly attaches it to the message according to MIME standard.

Comment: Why are you using `-a ${zip_final.zip}` instead of just `-a zip_final.zip` ? `${zip_final.zip}` means the value of a **variable** that is called `zip_final.zip`, but because this is an illegal variable name, shell with respond with error: `bad substitution`. This is probably the reason why your command isn't executing.

Comment: @raj  YMMV. I used `mailx -a` fine in the past, but my present Mint distro seems to have a BSD mailx where -a adds "additional headers". The `-A` option shown in another answer also does not exist. uuencode and uudecode are absent too.

Comment: [Cross posted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72782221/2344631) to StackOverflow :-(

Answer (score 1):

Here is a corrected sample script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#<$1    : zip file name
#<$2 ...: recipients
file=$1
shift
(
echo "  Hi team, sent zip file."
echo "  Files inside it are  :"
unzip -l "$file"
echo "  Thank you."
) |
mailx -A "$file" -s "Files list | Zip file" "$@"
```

What you missed:

- `mail -A` was coded `-a`
  *edit: it depends on mailx implementation*
- `unzip -Z` was unexpected
  *edit: it changes output style*
- there was no mail recipients
- `${zip_final.zip}` had no meaning

Comment: `mailx -a` works for me. There are different versions of `mailx` that differ in the switches they support. `-Z` is a correct parameter for `unzip`. `unzip -Zl` and `unzip -l` differ in the output format, but both list contents of the zipfile.

Comment: @raj you're right, I was too confident in that my own mailx version told the truth. For such a functionality it is deceptive.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
export files_list=`unzip -Zl zip_final.zip`
uuencode zip_final.zip zip_final.zip |mailx  -s 'Files list | Zip file' << EOM

   Hi team, sent zip file.
   Files inside it are  :  $files_list

   Thank you.
EOM
```

`uuencode` command will "convert" binary file to ASCII and will be able to send it via mail

Comment: No, `mailx` with the `-a` parameter should correctly MIME encode the attachment, no need to use `uuencode`. OP's problem is different - he says that `mailx` command is not called at all.

Comment: @raj, the error is in the OP script. I try in my idea to correct some of them.

Comment: Also, `uuencode` is not a standard way to add attachments to mail and is considered obsolete now, so the recipient wouldn't be able to easily extract the file from the message.

Comment: Yes, the error is in the OP script - he uses `${zip_final.zip}` instead of just `zip_final.zip`. That is probably the problem.

Comment: @raj, not only in the name of attached file

Answer (score 0):

The probable reason why your command isn't executed is that you use `-a ${zip_final.zip}` instead of just `-a zip_final.zip`.

`${zip_final.zip}` means the **value of a variable** that is called `zip_final.zip`. But this is an illegal variable name that the shell cannot interpret and so it responds with the error: `bad substitution`. That seems to be the problem.

Replace `${zip_final.zip}` with `zip_final.zip` and your script should work.